# Conditional summation in r

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with 63 columns and 1128 rows.

The columns consist of weightsrep, lon lat, v1.....v60, where v[i] represents precipitation data.

I want to create a vector [1:60] which contains the sum of weightsrep where v is not equal to 0.

For example (imagine these as columns):

If weights rep = 0.2,0.3,0.2

and v1 = 10,0,8

then sum of weightreps = 0.2+0.2

Comment: You can just use normal R subsetting, like `sum(df$weightsrep[!(df$v==0)])`

Comment: provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(rep=c(0.2,0.3,0.2),
                 lon=c(35,36,37),
                 lat=c(-90,-91,-92),
                 v1=c(10,0,8),
                 v2=c(3,4,5),
                 v3=c(9,20,4))

v <- as.vector("numeric")
for(i in 1:3) v[i] <- sum(df$rep[df[,i+3]!=0])
```